# awk script grouping with array

Tags: arrays, awk, grouping

i am trying to execute awk script below on solaris but it's giving error like

```
awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: bailing out near line 3
```

where is error can you help me to fix it ?

Input file:

```
$ cat details.txt
Manager1|sw1
Manager3|sw5
Manager1|sw4
Manager2|sw9
Manager2|sw12
Manager1|sw2
Manager1|sw0
```

Output required:
Group the similar (based on $1) fields($2) together, i.e. group the engineers which are under a particular common manager. i.e. required output:

```
Manager1|sw1,sw4,sw2,sw0
Manager2|sw9,sw12
Manager3|sw5
```

Awk solution:

```
$ awk '
   BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
   !A[$1] {A[$1] = $0; next}
   {A[$1] = A[$1] "," $2}
   END {for(i in A) {print A[i]}
}' details.txt
```

Comment: Use <code> tags or <pre> to surround your code.  <pre> is easier sometimes.

Comment: What version of awk? Everything is ok on gnu awk 3.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris ... You probably need to run "nawk" instead of "awk".

Answer (score 1):

in solaris, use nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by running the following script:

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($0,arr,"|");
    if(arr[1] in dic)  
    {
        dic[arr[1]]=dic[arr[1]]","arr[2];
    }
    else
    {
         dic[arr[1]]=arr[2];
    }
}END{for(i in dic)print i"|"dic[i]}' in.log > "out.log"
```